# Link to download Db2 11.5 Mod 7 Fix Pack 0

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, db2

I found two sources to add them as maven dependency for `JDBC 4.0 Driver (db2jcc4.jar) v11.5 M7 FP0 4.31.10 (JCC)`.
One is the `IBM` official download [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6524304). Another one is the [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.db2/jcc/11.5.7.0) from `mvn` repository which I can include dependency in my project.

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.db2/jcc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
    <version>11.5.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have no option to validate whether these two are the same `Db2 11.5 Mod 7 Fix Pack 0` except the signature which matches with the `mvn dependency version`

[image]

**Can someone help me to validate that these two are same `JDBC 4.0 Driver (db2jcc4.jar) v11.5 M7 FP0 4.31.10 (JCC)`?**

Comment: `java -cp /path/to/the/file/db2jcc4.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version`

Comment: What's the result of the command above on these 2 jar files?

Comment: It was same `4.31.10`

Comment: This means, that both these drivers have the same version.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein yes. can you answer the question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Db2 JCC driver version can be obtained by the following command.

```
> java -cp /path/to/the/file/db2jcc4.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version
IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.31.10
```